# how i can pass parameters in restTemplate to controller's put method

Tags: java, spring, web, resttemplate

I have a problem with passing parameters.
I have names in my income app and i want to update them by passing a parameters of new names from my rest app.
This is my code:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8084/rest/api/income/UpdateName/{oldName}/{newName}"; // the Url of the rest


    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
    params.put("oldName", oldName);
    params.put("newName", newName);
    Income income = new Income();

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.put(url, income, params);
    System.out.println(params);
}
```

This code is not working unfortunately, what can I do?

This is the put method in the controller :

```
@CrossOrigin
@GetMapping("/UpdateName/{oldName}/{clientName}") // view all incomes ..
public GeneralResponse viewAllIncome(@PathVariable("oldName") String oldName,@PathVariable("clientName") String clientName) {

    return new GeneralResponse(incomeServiceTemplate.updateClientName(oldName,clientName));

}
```

Comment: @GetMapping... it's mapped for http get not put

Answer (score 1):

The endpoint is `GET` not `PUT`, just append the parameters in the URL and call:

```
String url = "http://localhost:8084/rest/api/income/UpdateName/"+oldName+"/"+newName;

RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
restTemplate.getForObject(url, Income.class);
```

Or there's a better way, use `uriComponentsBuilder`. It takes care of url encoding:

```
UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromHttpUrl(url)
    .queryParam("oldName", oldName)
    .queryParam("newName", newName);
restTemplate.getForEntity(builder.build().encode().toUri(), Income.class);
```

Comment: i have this error : 2018-12-28 14:52:53.501  INFO 2920 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] .s.a.AnnotationAsyncExecutionInterceptor : No task executor bean found for async processing: no bean of type TaskExecutor and no bean named 'taskExecutor' either

Comment: I'm sorry its not work .. i dont know whats the problem